# Python - Passing argparse variables into class

Tags: python

Using Python 2.6, I want to pass `args` to the class but I'm getting the following error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "./myscript.py", line 95, in <module>
args = get_parser().parse_args()
File "./myscript.py", line 22, in get_parser
generate_mutex.set_defaults(func=ns_calls.generate_lbvs_bindings)
NameError: global name 'ns_calls' is not defined
```

Main script:

```
# myscript.py
from myclassfile import *

def get_parser():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    subparsers = parser.add_subparsers(dest="subparser_name")

    generate = subparsers.add_parser('generate')
    generate_mutex = generate.add_mutually_exclusive_group(required=True)
    generate_mutex.add_argument('-g', '--servicegroupname', help='The servicegroup name.',metavar='<servicegroup name>')
    generate_mutex.add_argument('-l', '--lbvservername', help='The virtual erver name to which the service is bound.',metavar='<lbvserver name>')
    generate_mutex.set_defaults(func=ns_calls.generate_lbvs_bindings)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = get_parser().parse_args()
    args.func(args)
    ns_calls = NetscalerCalls(args)
```

My module file:

```
# myclassfile.py

class NetscalerCalls(object):
    def __init__(self, args):
        self.lbvservername = args.lbvservername
        self.servername = args.servername
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't put the args in here:

```
ns_calls = NetscalerCalls()
                          ^
```

This is invalid according to the class you created, where `__init__` requires `(self, args)`.

When you initiate the class, it passes in `self` automatically. So you need to pass in the args when initiating the class.

**For example**:

```
# myscript.py
from myclassfile import *

...
...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    args = get_parser().parse_args()
    args.func(args)
    ns_calls = NetscalerCalls(args)
```

**If you try to pass in args before it is declared, it will fail**

That is why I have placed the variable declaration for `ns_calls` underneath the declaration for `args`

Comment: Ah makes sense. So now I have a different issue where it's telling me `ns_calls` is not defined. See latest updates.

Comment: That is covered in the last section of my answer

Comment: Grrrrr ... sorry I didnt update the edit correctly. I did move `ns_calls` down to the `main` block. (Python newbie here). Do I need to pass ns_calls into `get_parser()`?

Comment: You need to spend some time learning about scoping, and how that works with functions, classes, and globally in your code. Your `get_parser` function has a reference to `ns_calls`, but your `ns_calls` class requires the `args` variable, which you seem to declare first by calling the `get_parser` function... do you see where this is going?

Comment: yep. not a problem. I'm going to rework this. Thanks.

Comment: No problem. Keep at it. You'll get there.

Answer (score 1):

Your **init** requires you to pas an args parameters, but when you do the line `ns_calls = NetscalerCalls()` you aren't passing that parameter in so it complains.  You would have to that line after you have the args object you want then do `ns_calls = NetscalerCalls( args )`

Comment: Damnit, I did do that, I was in the wrong backup script. Getting a different error now. I think my issue is where `if __name__ == "__main__":` is

Comment: With your new edit you have to move the `ns_calls = NetscalerCalls(args)` line to below the line where you define args after the `if __name__ == "__main__":` line (which is fine as near as I can tell).  But where you create ns_calls now is too soon, because you haven't defined args until later in the script

Comment: @luckytaxi Foolowing your edits you have circular dependencies.  In effect NetscalerCalls depends on the results of get_parser, but get_parser depends on methods from NetscalerCalls.  You have to split those dependencies somehow.  Both cannot depend on each other or you'll never have the piece that you can do first.